# Excel web query not recognizing tables on the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel

Customers use web queries to grab data in the tables directly from our website and place them into excel where they can automatically work on it. while trying to grab data from our website, we noticed that table markers were not shown. excel is unable to recognize the tables on the web page.

Website was developed using RoR.

can someone help us with this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include the relevant RoR code. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: I don't care too much about the RoR code, but rather about the rendered html, since that is what the Excel client will see. In many cases, using Power Query will produce better results than regular web queries.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using Power Query instead of regular web queries. With the "from Web" option you can get the DOM into Power Query and access any DOM element.